# POST after disabling button on Google Chrome doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I create ASP .NET MVC application. On button click I call JavaScript that disable same button.
After that (button has property readonly disabled) post action doesn't call. When I remove JavaScript that disable buttons everything is fine. This happens only in the Google Chrome.

When I try same example in Firefox or Internet Explorer everything is fine.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        Enable();
    });


    function Enable() {
        $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#btn').removeAttr('readonly');
    }

    function Disable() {
        $('#btn').attr('disabled', 'true');
        $('#btn').attr('readonly', 'true');
    }
</script>
<h2>Example</h2>

<form>
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="StackOverflow" onclick="Disable()" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should use `$('...').prop('disabled', false);` for those attributes ([source](http://api.jquery.com/prop/))

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Prevent the form being submitted twice?

Comment: @DidierG. OP is using `jquery 1.4.4`, `prop` is available in 1.6 or higher i think

Comment: @nachito - Yes, I try prevent form being submitted twice. I also try include jQuery 1.7 and try with $('...').prop('disabled', false) but doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call form.submit() before disabling the button, and return false from your event handler.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">



<head>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

<title>Untitled 1</title>

</head>



<body>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 



<script type="text/javascript"> 



    jQuery(document).ready(function () { 

        Enable(); 

    }); 





    function Enable() { 

        $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled'); 

        $('#btn').removeAttr('readonly'); 

    } 



    function Disable() { 

        $('#myform').submit();



        $('#btn').attr('disabled', 'true'); 

        $('#btn').attr('readonly', 'true'); 



        return false;

    } 

</script> 

<h2>Example</h2> 



<form id="myform" method="post"> 

    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="StackOverflow" onclick="return Disable()" /> 

</form> 



</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function Disable() {
    $('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#btn').attr('readonly', 'readonly');

   $("form").submit();
}
```

edit

```
change the `input` type to `button`

<form>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="StackOverflow" />
</form>

$(function(e){
$("#btn").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //if you can use latest version of jquery and use .prop("disabled",true)
$("form").submit();
});

});
```

Comment: Doesnt' help. Function disable button but POST to server doesn't work. When I doesn't call this function everything is fine.

Comment: I'm trying prevent submit same data multiple times. That's all. After click when POST occurs submit button is enabled and nervous user clicking on the button multiple times. After that we have multiple but same data. If button is disabled after click, because POST takes 20 seconds everything would be ok.

Comment: This solution is ok, but solution from Steven is little bit better for me. Thanks again.